# Is there a difference between using ContractName.func and func when calling func in a given contract?

Tags: solidity, contract-design

I have started to learn solidity with _buildspaces tutorials. In these tuto we have for example:

```
contract MyContract {
    function foo() internal view returns (uint memory) {
        return 0;
    }
    function bar() public {
        uint memory tmp = foo()
        ...
    }
}
```

In some other contracts I have seen the `foo` function being referenced as `MyContract.foo`.

Does this make a difference? Why not `this`? I am also not sure to understand the difference for getter, see https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.9/contracts.html#getter-functions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a difference between `foo` and `MyContract.foo` that only makes sense when there's inheritance in the contract and the same function is declared several contracts.

For `foo()`, since no contract is specified, the compiler uses [C3 Linearization](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.10/contracts.html#multiple-inheritance-and-linearization) to determine which function will invoke.

For `MyContract.foo()` you are explicitly telling the compiler which function you want to call. You use it when you want to resolve an ambiguity, or an explicit ordering of the function calls.

The last one `this.foo()` is only used for external functions. You should be aware that inside foo execution `msg.sender` will be the contract address.

Comment: If `MyContract` inherits from `IMyContract`, does this mean that `MyContract.foo` will use parent's implementation while `foo` while use the one overloading it in `MyContract` if it exists and if not, the parents's one?

Comment: @ClementWalter With `MyContract.foo` the compiler fails if MyContract doesn't define the function foo.